# Data grouped in 12 month period

Tags: oracle, date

I have 2 tables

```
Create table t (
  employee varchar2(10), 
  job varchar2(5), 
  start_date date, 
  end_date date, 
  amt number
);
```

With the following data

```
insert into t values (1111,1,19-May-2008,20-May-2008,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,19-May-2010,19-May-2010,7);  
insert into t values (1111,1,01-Jul-2010,01-Jul-2010,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,13-Feb-2012,13-Feb-2012,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,27-Nov-2013,27-Nov-2013,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,28-Nov-2013,28-Nov-2013,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,24-Aug-2014,24-Aug-2014,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,25-Aug-2014,25-Aug-2014,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,24-Aug-2015,25-Aug-2015,14);

insert into t values (1111,1,14-Nov-2015,14-Nov-2015,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,15-Nov-2015,16-Nov-2015,14);

insert into t values (1111,1,11-Sep-2016,11-Sep-2016,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,29-Sep-2016,29-Sep-2016,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,10-Nov-2016,10-Nov-2016,7);

insert into t values (1111,1,14-Nov-2016,15-Nov-2016,14);

Create table t1 (
  employee varchar2(10), 
  job varchar2(5), 
  start_date date,       
  commence_date date,
);
```

With the following data

```
Insert into t values (1111, 1, 14-Nov-2007, 19-May-2007);
```

I am trying to list amt to be displayed grouped by 12 month period, starting from commence_date. Result should return EMPLOYEE, JOB, PERIOD_START, PERIOD_END, AMT. If there are no amt to display in an year, then "AMT" column will display "0". The result should look like below.

```
1111 1 19/05/2007 17/05/2008 0

1111 1 19/05/2008 18/05/2009 7

1111 1 19/05/2009 18/05/2010 0

1111 1 19/05/2010 18/05/2011 7

1111 1 19/05/2011 18/05/2012 14

1111 1 19/05/2012 18/05/2013 0

1111 1 19/05/2013 18/05/2014 14

1111 1 19/05/2014 18/05/2015 14

1111 1 19/05/2015 18/05/2016 35

1111 1 19/05/2016 18/05/2017 35
```

I have tried to do this. However I am not been able to display the rows where there were no amt. example row 1 in expected result. Any help or suggestions will be much appreciated.

following is the query I was using

```
SELECT DISTINCT
ss.EMPLOYEE,
ss.JOB,  
ss.start_date commence,
ss.Year_frm_start Year,  
SUM(ss.AMT) Over (Partition BY ss.EMPLOYEE, ss.JOB, ss.Year_frm_start) amt,
  ss.start_date +numtoyminterval(ss.Year_frm_start,'Year') period_start,
  (ss.start_date -1)+numtoyminterval(ss.Year_frm_start+1,'Year') period_end 
FROM
(
SELECT
  t.EMPLOYEE,
  t.JOB,
  t.AMT,      
  t1.start_date,
  floor((t.start_DATE - t1.start_date) / 365) Year_frm_start     
 FROM
  t,t1
WHERE      
t.employee=t1.employee and t.job=t1.job
  ORDER BY
  t.start_date
 )
 ss  
where ss.EMPLOYEE = '1111'
ORDER BY
ss.EMPLOYEE,
ss.Year_frm_start
;
```

Comment: The example for the result does not contain year - from where is this column fetched? Just to clarify the user enters a commence date `d` and the query returns employees who were employed between `d` and a year after, right?

Comment: Is this Oracle or SQL Server? It is very rarely both. Please edit your post, find the tabs at the bottom, and delete the incorrect one. Thanks!

Comment: What is the question ? You showed us what do you want, but I can't see what a problem is.

Comment: Just to clarify, user enters an employee number and date commenced, then the query displays amount within each anniversary. If no amount to display, query will display "0"

Comment: It seems you need some kind of sequential generator to produce 1-y intervals. Then left outer join intervals with `t` data